# How to update only one row in table but with id number

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

[image: Table screenshot]

How to join row 2 to row 1 (id = 24, count = 2) and row 5 to row 4 (id = 27, count = 3)

Comment: please clarify question further. Please add information about what do you have and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am not clear if you simply want to sum by bill and food or update row 1 and 4 then delete row 2 and 5.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yeah P.Salmon, like I want to fix the bill. This result is because I entered 2 bills but do not want to repeat the idfood so I want to pool. I can use string select but I want to use string update in SQL to merge duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below SQL query will help you to get result set you want.

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id, idBill, idFood,
    SUM(count) AS count
FROM Table1
GROUP BY idFood, idBill
```